# What content should be sent via LinkedIn InMail to a job poster?

Tags: linkedin

When applying for jobs on LinkedIn, I like to send inmail messages to the job poster. Since the person posting the job is related to hiring, I send an inmail equivalent to my Cover Letter.

Since I apply separately with my Cover Letter attached, I am concerned that the job poster may see both and look negatively at the InMail message as a result.

When sending InMail, how should I decide what to include in it?

Comment: This needs to be more of a question than asking for tips in general

Comment: Follow the instructions in the actual job post.

Comment: Hey user, and welcome to [workplace.se]. Your question was collecting close votes and down votes, so I tried to give it an [edit] to make it in line with the guidelines in our [help/on-topic]. If you think I missed something or can improve it, please feel free to make an [edit] yourself. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation is don't - follow the procedure as the job advert says. Deliberately bypassing systems like that works in films, but rarely in real life. At best they may see it as eager, but they're more likely to find it intrusive and a little off putting. Or, to put it another way - it has little chance of influencing the outcome positively; cold calling is something that should be practiced with extreme care, even moreso when you have a means of progressing already.

Answer (score 1):

Your InMail to the job poster should contain whatever information they requested you to send to them.

If the job advertisement says to go to a website and apply through there, then there is nothing to put in an InMail.  If that is the case, then you should consider why you want to end them an InMail at all.  You could send them an InMail saying that you are highly interested in working for their company for [these reasons] and have applied for the position that they posted, and ask if there are other similar positions available.

If the job advertisement tells you to email someone to apply, then follow those instructions.  If the email is to someone who is not the job poster, you can decide whether you want to treat this as analogous to the above case.

And, of course, if the job advertisement tells you to contact the job poster with specific information, you give them the information that they have requested.

Remember that the job poster might not have anything to do with hiring.  I've noticed that some companies have one person post all of their LinkedIn ads.  When a company has 50+ LinkedIn ads across many different types of jobs, it's highly unlikely that the person who is posting them knows anything about it.  If you are going to send an InMail to the job poster, you should evaluate whether there is any benefit to you in doing so.  If the person who is posting is essentially just a job aggregator for that company, I'm not sure if there is any benefit.

In each case, the question is whether the communication is beneficial to you.  And, as with everything else that you do when looking for a job, this question needs to be answered with every piece of communication that you send (or are thinking of sending).  Just as you should tailor your cover letter and resume to the individual position, you should ensure that the rest of your communication is tailored to the individual position and the person with whom you are communicating.  Having a single policy what goes into any given piece of communication reduces your opportunities to show how you really are the best person for the job that is being advertised.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should send an inmail most of the time. It shows initiative, especially if you are going after sales positions, it might help your resume get to the top of the pile. What do you have to lose? Having said that, the wording needs to be careful and the sender must understand that there are legal issues regarding responses. I follow Liz Ryan's recommendations from the [Human Workplace](http://humanworkplace.com/), we are not robots ! This is a human business and HR people should not be in HR if they are not interested in the Human aspect.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I feel I should add my 2 cents. I think it depends on the personality of the person your trying to contact.  I contacted the Senior VP of Operations of my company and he actually called me 2 days later.  I really don't think it looks bad because worst case scenario, they delete your message.  Nothing ventured nothing gained.